# iOS readonly and retain are mutually exclusive

Tags: objective-c

I want to have a strong readonly property. When I use this code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *test;
```

I get a warning: "Property attributes 'readonly' and 'retain' are mutually exclusive". How can I solve this warning?

Comment: Why do you want that? Presumably you are declaring the property `readwrite` privately (or is that missing)?

Comment: I would like that other classes can only get the test property and not set it

Comment: Ok, but you have to set the value or return a value somewhere - where is that?

Comment: In the init method I would be able to set it through _test right?

Comment: Cannot find the reference right now but it's a known bug in the clang version which shipped with Xcode 5.0.2. Using the 5.1 beta this (false) error does not appear anymore ;)

Comment: Ok I will wait it out ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a property in your continuation category which redefines the variable as `readwrite`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *test;
```

Now, publicly the property is read only, but privately you can write it. The compiler will generate the methods you need and allow you to call them.